# ARToolkit for Unity on Android : Camera won't start, just black screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I've been working on a project with ARToolkit for Unity. I built it to Android APK. I then installed it to my Xiaomi device. When I run the app, it does the following :

1. It pops out a small square camera on the upper left corner
2. It shows unity animation text as usual
3. It then goes black forever

I've already set the permission for the app to access the phone's camera. How can I solve this matter?

Do I have to do something to get the phone's camera working? I am newbie by the way so don't go harsh on me.

Notes : I've tried to build another scene without ARToolkit to Android APK. It worked just fine and no black screen.

Sorry if my english isn't that good. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks before.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am stuck at same place

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess... ARToolkit for Android on startup attempts to contact a web-server on the Internet to download camera parameters.  I've noticed if your phone does not have Internet access, you'll see a black screen for quite a while (at least 30 seconds I've seen) until the HTTP request times out.  You can see this if you run Android Studio studio and view the logs for your app.  Unfortunately at the moment there appears to be no switch to turn this off. See:

http://artoolkit.org/community/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=9441